# .htaccess rewrite rule did not work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my site there is a membershp system. Users' profile page likes `profile.php?u=username` I want to show url like `http://sitename.com/username` So I wrote in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^profile profile.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]
```

When you go to `http://sitename.com/profile`, the page shows general information about system. And `http://sitename.com/username` shows username profile. But When I want to go `http://sitename.com`, `http://sitename.com/profile` psgr show, the index.page (main page) not shown. How can I do it?

Comment: You say the index page is not shown; is the profile page shown?* If so, try changing `^([^/]*)$` to `^([^/]+)$` (the `*` quantifier matches __0__ or more times, which may also redirect the homepage).
Edit: *That is: is the profile page shown at `http://sitename.com`?

Comment: Profile page shown at `http://sitename.com/profile`. Profile page's real address is `http://sitename.com/profile.php` Index page's real address `http://sitename.com/index.php`. So I tried it `^([^/]+)$`but unfortunally it is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^profile/?$ profile.php [L]

RewriteRule ^ads/?$ advertisement.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Everything was good. But when I want to go other file `ads.php` and it's url `http://sitename.com/advertisement`, `profile.php` (`http://sitename.com/profile`) page is shown. I think, I can not manage it!

Comment: Ok I have updated the code. Though I on mobile now so won't be able to closely monitor this thread for few hours.